# What are these bitwise operators doing?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I always struggled with bitwise operators and their practical usage. I found an example online for something I am doing in C++ and was wondering what is going on there.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; ++i)
    {
        queue->push(temp[i] & 0xff);
        queue->push((temp[i] >> 8) & 0xff);
    }
```

I know roughly what the "And" and the "Shift" operator is doing, but how does that affect the temp variable and the result. Anyone can help understand that?

Comment: temp variable does not affected, expression results will pushed to queue, first expression extracts lower 8 bits of `temp[i]` (bits 0-7), second one - next 8 bit, bits 8-15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first statement, `temp[i] & 0xff`, extracts the lower 8 bits because 0xff = 1111 1111.

The second statement, `(temp[i] >> 8) & 0xff` , first shifts the bits in temp[i] to the right by 8 times, so the bits from position 8 to position 15 will now occupy bits from position 0 to position 7. And when you do the bitwise & with 0xFF, you get the new bits from position 0 to position 7.

For example -

Let's say, `temp[i] = 0x01020304`
then `temp[i] & 0xff = 0x04`
and `(temp[i] >> 8) & 0xff = 0x03`

Answer (score 0):

The temp variable is not affected in either operation.  The first logical operation is isolating the low order 8 bits of the temp variable and pushing them onto the queue, the second operation is isolating the next 8 bits (numbers 8 through 15) and is pushing them onto the queue.  These two operations are repeated size/2 times.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: Learn to love `std::bitset`. It comes in handy quite often when juggling with bits. Consider this code:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    unsigned long x = 12345678;

    std::bitset<32> a{ x} ;
    std::bitset<32> b{ x & 0xff };
    std::bitset<32> c{ (x >> 8) & 0xff };
    std::bitset<32> d{ 0xff };
    std::cout << a  << '\n' << b << '\n' << c << '\n' << d;
}
```

Its output is (comments added)

```
00000000101111000110000101001110             // x
00000000000000000000000001001110             // x & 0xff
00000000000000000000000001100001             // (x>>8) & 0xff
00000000000000000000000011111111             // 0xff
```

So what is happening here is...

`0xff` is an integer literal with the 8 lower bits set. The bitwise and `&` allows you to mask bits, ie the result has those bits set that are set in both operands. The shift operator `>>` shifts the bits by the specified amount (8 in this case).

In total, your code first pushes the first 8 bits and then the next 8 bits into the queue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate. Now I know this will sound stupid, but what would be the point of shifting bits to the left or the right? How can anyone think in this way. I am sure I am missing something. Can you give me a practical example say in audio for example? thank you! :)

Comment: @KenJohn multiplying / dividing a number by powers of 2 is the most obvious example